# Accessing QGIS plugins in Python?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Is there a way to access QGIS plugins in Python?

I'd like to write a script to do some geoprocessing, and I'd like to use the clip, regular points and convex hull tools in fTools, as well as the Road graph plugin. The latter is probably a different can of worms because it is a C++ rather than Python plugin.

Answer (score 21):

If you know the python module for the plugin you can just run a import in the python console For example:

```
from fTools import somemodule
```

Then you can do somemodule.methodcall().  You will have to make sure, by looking at the code of the plugin, that it doesn't rely on any of it gui stuff.  Otherwise you might get a nice UI pop up when you don't want it.

But yes it's possible.