# Automate Running Shortest Path

Tags: qgis, python, vector, shortest-path

I have to use a qgis method (python, plugin, scripts) only to automate a shortest path calculation for multiple start and end points. How might i automate the shortest path road graph tool?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How to access the road graph plugin in python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59376/how-to-access-the-road-graph-plugin-in-python)