# Using QGIS plugins from Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Is there a simple way to automate calls to QGIS plugins from a QGIS Python script? Either from console or a plugin?

I am ideally looking for a way to specify input/output parameters and bypass GUI.

Specifically, I'm trying to use the SimpleSVG plugin in a script that generates a whole bunch of maps.

Comment: I just saw [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/11216) question... Sorry, didn't find it when searching. I don't assume anything has changed the last 2 years?

Comment: You're right, the situation has not changed.