# Possible to run "Merge shapefiles to one" algorithm from Python script?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, merge

Developing a python script in QGIS 2.2, I can run algorithms from the **Processing** plugin fine such as those from *QGIS geoalgorithms* and *SAGA*.

Can you do the same for the algorithm "*Merge shapefiles to one*" from the **Vector** menu and how can you call it from the Python console?

The "*Merge shapefiles to one*" algorithm is from the Ftools plugin.

Found a link which might be useful: [Accessing QGIS plugins in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11216)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question on how to access other algorithms such as those from MMQGIS has been asked with an answer given:

[How to use the MMQGIS plugin through the Python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103715/how-to-use-the-mmqgis-plugin-through-the-python-console)