# Using MMQGIS plugin through Python console?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, mmqgis

I know how to make Hub Lines using the GUI, I want to know how to do the same using the Python Console, a tutorial would be great.

Comment: Could you add some more information please? We don't know if you are looking for a link or a tutorial or something entirely different.

Comment: I know how create the Hub Lines, I want to know how to do it using the python console. A tutorial would be great. Thank you.

Comment: @amamdouh, you've just restated your question almost verbatim.  Could you please add more information as Paul suggested?  What have you tried so far?  Could you post any code you've written?

Comment: I asked a similar question and found this which may be of some use: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/is-there-a-way-to-access-qgis-plugins-in-python

Comment: it's what I am looking for, but I can't find the code for MMQGIS plugin anywhere. thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When I don't know a Python module, I use the `dir()`command or the [see module](https://github.com/inky/see) to know what's inside.

(in the Python console)

```
from see import see
import mmqgis
dir(mmqgis)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'classFactory', 'mmqgis_dialogs', 'mmqgis_library', 'mmqgis_menu']
# or
see(mmqgis)
.classFactory()    .mmqgis_dialogs    .mmqgis_library    .mmqgis_menu
```

`classFactory()`, `.mmqgis_dialogs()` or `.mmqis_menu()` are clearly for the interface of the plugin, so the functions that you are looking for are in `.mmqgis_library`.

You can try:

```
see(mmqgis.mmqgis_library)
(lot of items)
```

but it is more interesting here to find the original  `mmqgis_library` Python file:

```
import mmqgis.mmqgis_library
mmqgis.mmqgis_library.__file__
'/.../.qgis2/python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_library.pyc'
```

The file concerned is mmqgis_library.py with (lines 3202 ...):

```
# --------------------------------------------------------
#    mmqgis_hub_distance - Create shapefile of distances
#              from points to nearest hub
# --------------------------------------------------------

class mmqgis_hub:
   def __init__(self, point, newname):
      self.point = point
      self.name = newname
 ....
```

So:

```
from mmqgis.mmqgis_library import mmqgis_hub
```

Works, but after you need to understand the class to use it...

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else who is starting out with the python console, here's the outline of how I used the MMQGIS's geocoding function, which locally geocodes using the Census' streetfiles (with the NA's changed to zeros), after I had already installed MMQGIS :

```
#setup
import mmqgis.mmqgis_library
from mmqgis.mmqgis_library import mmqgis_geocode_street_layer
fpath_input_addr="/Users/mollybryan/Documents/geocoding/to_geocode/bladder/attempt20230504_"
fpath_input_cty="/Users/mollybryan/Documents/geocoding/street_files/address_feature_nonull/clean"
fpath_output="/Users/mollybryan/Documents/geocoding/automation_attempts/"


#the geocode function
def rungeocode():
    input_layer = QgsVectorLayer(input_layer_name)

    message = mmqgis_geocode_street_layer(input_csv_name, \
        number_column, street_name_column, zip_column, \
        input_layer, street_name_attr, left_from_attr, left_to_attr, left_zip_attr, \
        right_from_attr, right_to_attr, right_zip_attr, \
        from_x_attr, from_y_attr, to_x_attr, to_y_attr, setback, \
        output_file_name, not_found_file)

    print("Geocode Street Layer: " + str(message))

#variables that don't change
number_column = "geo_num"
street_name_column = "geo_street"
zip_column = "zip"

street_name_attr = "FULLNAME"
left_from_attr = "LFROMHN"
left_to_attr = "LTOHN"
left_zip_attr = "ZIPL"
right_from_attr = "RFROMHN"
right_to_attr = "RTOHN"
right_zip_attr = "ZIPR"

from_x_attr = None
from_y_attr = None
to_x_attr = None
to_y_attr = None
setback = 0

#list of the counties
lst_cty=["12095","12097","12117"]

#runit
for x in lst_cty:
    print("beginning "+x)
    input_csv_name=fpath_input_addr+x+".csv"
    input_layer_name=fpath_input_cty+x+".shp"
    output_file_name=fpath_output+x+".shp"
    not_found_file=fpath_output+x+"_rejects.csv"
    
    rungeocode()
```