# How to save postgres table to kml without losing attributes using python

Tags: postgresql, pyqgis

I am saving the postgres table loaded in QGIS to kml.

```
qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(aLayer, myFile, "ogr", projDest, "KML")
```

But the output file does not have the attributes. So if I want to convert/save the table into KML without losing attributes how can this be done using python.

Answer (score 2):

KML is a XML format. In theory, you don't need  ogr nor QGIS, you can use all the [Python XML modules](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=xml&submit=search) (standard [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.5.0b1), ...) in combination with the [psycopg2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2/2.6.1) module (or using the QGIS layer)

They are also many specific solutions in the [Python Packages Index (Pypi):kml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=kml&submit=search). The easiest to use are [simplekml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplekml/0.5.0), [keytree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keytree/0.2.1) or [pykml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykml/0.1.0)

This will require more work than using ogr and you may not get exactly what you want because the KML format it's not great for storing attributes as a data store (look at [Perrygeo: Converting Shapefiles (and more) to KML](http://blog.perrygeo.net/2006/07/14/converting-shapefiles-and-more-to-kml/)  or [GDAL: KML - Keyhole Markup Language](http://www.gdal.org/drv_kml.html))

Another solution is to use the "Google Maps (tm) KML Export Form" of the [MMQGIS](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) plugin  (look at [How to use the MMQGIS plugin through the Python console?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103840/2581))

> This tool exports features to KML with the capability to explicitly specify fields for the Name and Description that are always displayed in the current (as of this writing) default Google Maps (tm) interface.

The function is `mmqgis_kml_export` (in the mmqgis_library.py file)

```
from mmqgis.mmqgis_library import mmqgis_kml_export
```

But you need to understand the function to use it...

Comment: I have solved the issue. In writeAsVectorFormat there is option called datasourceOptions where we can change the name and the description. Datalist=['AltitudeMode=relativeToGround','NameField=id']
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(aLayer, myFile, "ogr", crs, "KML",datasourceOptions =(Datalist)).

Comment: You should add this as an answer.