# No module named 'mmqgis'

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, nearest-neighbor

I have two layers in my Project

1)Points Layers

2) Polygon Layer

I need to apply nearest neighbour Analysis between point and Polygon, but i am unable to get .

I tried the below code.I am using **Qgis 3.0**

```
from mmqgis import mmqgis_library as mmqgis
```

As soon i added this line in my python console it got

> No module name mmqgis found

Comment: This thread may help you: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103715/using-mmqgis-plugin-through-python-console

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720068/call-mmqgis-plugin-from-command-line

Comment: I was just reading about NNjoin , Nearest Neighbour and Mmqgis . Which one will suit my problem best ?

Comment: Please describe your neighboor analysis problem in a separate question. Clarify your situation, maybe a visualization helps.

Comment: @GregZ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295392/nearest-neighbour-analysis

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have installed this complement in QGIS 3.0.

Even if you installed it in your QGIS 2.18, you have to re-do it within the 3.0 interface.

[image]