# Nearest Neighbour Analysis Or NN join

Tags: pyqgis, nearest-neighbor, mmqgis, pyqgis-3

I have two Layer in my Project

1) Voronoi Layer which is constructed on point Layer

2) Building Layers which is represented as Polygon.

The **goal is to find the nearest node for every polygon** (building).

I am **using QGIS 3.0** and using python console within QGIS to automate this.

I am highly confused in below two approaches: NN join and Nearest Neighbour.

I am thinking to find the centroid of each polygon and then find the nearest node using the Distance Matrix Tool.

Small Green dots are Nodes and Polygon are Buildings.

[image]

Comment: have you tried this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62219/how-to-find-the-polygon-inside-which-a-point-lies
After that, you can join your Voronoi polygon to the corresponding points.

Comment: Nope, but how does it related it to my Problem ?

Comment: I guess the NNJoin will perform well: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168120/what-qgis-tool-or-plugin-is-equivalent-to-the-esri-near-tool