# How to run QGIS plugin from python script

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, topology, qgis-processing

I would like to access external QGIS plugins through a python script. I have been able to access the built in QGIS processing and vector toolbox, but have been unsuccessful with external plugins such as the topology checker plugin. I have tried this both using the built in QGIS python console, and an external IDE, but attempts have failed.

I am sure that there is a way to do this, has someone done this before?

Comment: It _should_ be possible, however I don't think there's been a solution posted which **directly** answers this type of question yet. I think the furthest we have gone with this topic are from these posts: [How to call the interpolation plugin from the python console?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103506/how-to-call-the-interpolation-plugin-from-the-python-console); and [Is there a way to access QGIS plugins in Python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11216/is-there-a-way-to-access-qgis-plugins-in-python).