# How to use Qgis Gridsplitter Plugin in Console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, splitting, qgis-python-console

I would like to use Gridsplitter plugin in console. I have the following code for doing it:

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
import imp

gridSplitterPath = "C:/Users/Mossy/.qgis2/python/plugins/gridSplitter/gridSplitter.py"
outputpath = "C:/Users/Mossy/Desktop/NewFolder/Output"
cutlayerpath = "C:/Users/Mossy/Desktop/NewFolder/InputData/cutlayer.shp"
layertocutpath = "C:/Users/Mossy/Desktop/NewFolder/InputData/layertocut.tif"

iface = qgis.utils.iface
module = imp.load_source("gridSplitter",gridSplitterPath)

mySplitter = module.gridSplitter(iface)
mySplitter.outputfolder = outputpath
mySplitter.layertocut = QgsRasterLayer(layertocutpath,"laytocut")
mySplitter.cutlayeris = True
mySplitter.cutlayer = QgsVectorLayer(cutlayerpath,"cutlay", "ogr")
mySplitter.pref = "cut_"
mySplitter.subfolderis = False
mySplitter.tileindexis = True

mySplitter.operate()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "c:/users/Mossy/appdata/local/temp/tmpqc7_fe.py", line 23, in <module>
mySplitter.operate()
File "C:/Users/Mossy/.qgis2/python/plugins/gridSplitter/gridSplitter.py", line 206, in operate
self.layertocutcrs= layertocut.crs()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs'
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: It says  in console.

Answer (score 4):

In the console, the plugins folder is in the PYTHONPATH (no need of `import imp`)

Simply use ([Is there a way to access QGIS plugins in Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11219))

```
import gridSplitter
gridSplitter.__file__
'/Users/my/.qgis2/python/plugins/gridSplitter/__init__.pyc'
```

The content of the module with [see (dir for humans)](https://github.com/araile/see)

```
see(gridSplitter)
help()                  .classFactory()         .gridSplitter
.gridSplitter_dialog    .resources_rc
```

The help of the module

```
help(gridSplitter)
Help on package gridSplitter:
NAME
gridSplitter
FILE
/Users/my/.qgis2/python/plugins/gridSplitter/__init__.py
DESCRIPTION
/***************************************************************************
 gridSplitter
                                 A QGIS plugin
 A plugin that cuts a layer into pieces(tiles)
                             -------------------
        begin                : 2015-03-26
        copyright            : (C) 2015 by Maximilian Krambach
        email                : maximilian.krambach@gmx.de
        git sha              : $Format:%H$
 ***************************************************************************/

/***************************************************************************
 *                                                                         *
 *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
 *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
 *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
 *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
 *                                                                         *
 ***************************************************************************/
 This script initializes the plugin, making it known to QGIS.

PACKAGE CONTENTS
gridSplitter
gridSplitter_dialog
resources_rc
FUNCTIONS
classFactory(iface)
    Load gridSplitter class from file gridSplitter. 
    :param iface: A QGIS interface instance.
    :type iface: QgsInterface
```

Therefore you can try

```
gridSplitter.classFactory(iface)
mySplitter = gridSplitter.gridSplitter
```

Answer (score 4):

Despite the author's intention, I think the plugin won't be easily usable out of QGIS (or even from the QGIS Python Console) as is.

Inside the `operate()` function, the code is relying on plugin dialogs and on dialog methods like:

```
self.dlg.OuptDir.text()
```

In particular, the error you're getting is due to [these lines](https://github.com/matakuka/gridsplitter/blob/2429d2e80120b5cf10bc3d9ce04ab3df0dd62bdd/gridSplitter.py#L203-L206) in `operate()`, which give `layertocut` a `None` value if you have not used the plugin's main dialog before:

```
index = self.dlg.inputRasterBox.currentIndex()
layertocut = self.dlg.inputRasterBox.itemData(index)
```

Then, accessing `crs()` is impossible in:

```
self.layertocutcrs= layertocut.crs()
```

Making the plugin "Non-GUI friendly" will need a refactor. You can add a feature request in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/matakuka/gridsplitter/issues) or, if it's critical to you, program it by yourself or hire the author to do it!

---

*Note that there is a GridSplitter v0.3.6 in GitHub that is still not available in QGIS plugins repository. I've checked that version as well, but it has similar problems, this time turning `outputfolder` into `None`.*